# TempMute | NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do something like the 'tempmute' command, but an error keeps popping up
:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
```

And here is the command code

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def tempmute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None, * time):
        if not member:
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Вы должны указать участника!', color=random.choice(colors)))
        else:
            LMUTED = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name='LMUTED')
            if not LMUTED:
                perms=discord.Permissions(send_messages=False)
                await ctx.guild.create_role(name='LMUTED', 
                colour=discord.Colour(0x0000FF),
                permissions = perms)
                await ctx.send(f'Я создал роль `{LMUTED}`!')
            await member.add_roles(member, LMUTED)
            await ctx.send(f'Я замьютил {member} на {time}!')
            await s(time * 60)
            await ctx.remove_roles(member, LMUTED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you know [how to read python errors](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/).

But the main issue here is that you don't assign `LMUTED` a value after you create a new role, so it is still `None` and thus discord.py fails to add the role.

Also, keep in mind that when you do things that expire over time, simply sleeping/waiting in the method is not a good way to handle it, as the thread might be locked. Instead you should use some sort of [scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html). Basically a thing that waits a certain amount of time before running some code.